# Double concatenation in different TextBox depending on category

Tags: vba, for-loop, foreach, textbox, concatenation

I don't know if somebody already asked a question about it or not, i'm new to VBA but i've already done some C# programming.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZy8M.png)

in Text :

```
For i = 1 To 5 'Category
For j = 1 To 7 'Each entry of the category
If UserForm1.Controls("Cat" & j & "Entry" & i).Value <> "" Then
    Range("A" & i).Value = UserForm1.Controls("Cat" & i & "Entry" & j).Value
End If
Next j
Next i
```

So this is basicaly what i'm trying to do, i have 2 categories, each one have 7 TextBox, depending on how many of them are filled, I wanted to put their values on a cell... But seems like the concatenation isn't working, also tried the For Each methods but no results..

[The interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTpSk.png)

Thank you guys

Comment: Also forgot to mention that i'm trying to do that because each TextBox is named like that : Cat1Entry1, Cat1Entry2... Cat2Entry1...

Comment: If that code is in the code-behind of `UserForm1`, then it's referring to the form's *default instance*, which may or may not be the instance being displayed. Change `UserFrom1` to `Me`, and avoid referring to forms' default instances in their own code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't concatenating anything you are overwriting cells A1-5 every time.

```
For i = 1 To 5 'Category
For j = 1 To 7 'Each entry of the category
If UserForm1.Controls("Cat" & j & "Entry" & i).Value <> "" Then
    if range("A" & i).value <> "" then
         Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & " " & UserForm1.Controls("Cat" & i & "Entry" & j).Value
    else 'Avoiding the space
         range("A" & i).value = Userform1.controls("Cat" & i & "Entry" & j).value
    end if
End If
Next j
Next i
```

Comment: The problem is that the line "UserForm1.Control("Cat" & j & "Entry" & i).Value >< "" then " gives me an error : Specified Object not found...

Comment: It works when i write in raw "UserForm1.Control("Cat1Entry2).Value does work but the concatenation don't...

Comment: Also, i'm not ,talking about concatenating cells values, i just want to take every value of my TextBoxes and put them into blank cells, and i don't want to do A1.value = TextBox1.value 30 times, so i'm trying to put it in a For instruction but seems like "Controls("Cat" & i & "Entry" & j).value is not recognized (Cause if i put directly the name of my TextBox like ..controls("Cat1Entry5") it works..

Comment: Does it fail on the first one? You can chain things together like that, so a name is probably wrong. You are iterating through 35 text boxes, and storing that in 5 cells, you either need to use a different variable for the cell address or concatenate something.